# Displaying DICOM MPR image in asp.net MVC view c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dicom

My application is asp.net MVC3; currently I can display DCIOM MPR images using image handler and storing the image in the session using:

```
objImage = im.Bitmap(outputSize, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, m);
context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
objImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream,     
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

It works fine, however when I rotate the image the response is very slow!!  I am trying to store the DICOM MPR in the controlloer as a session variable using the following:

```
............
DicomImageMPR mpr1 = new DicomImageMPR(volume);
mpr1.SetViewPlane(new Point3D(), new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), new Vector3D(0, 0, -1));
mpr1.Interpolation = InterpolationType3D.Trilinear;
MySession.Current.mpr1 = mpr1;
```

My question is how I can put the image in a viewbag to display in the view?  I would appreciate your suggestions, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using the following:

```
       public ActionResult GenerateImage()
            {
                FileContentResult result;
                System.Drawing.Image objImage = null;
              ....
                mpr = MySession.Current.mpr2;
                im = mpr;
               ...
                objImage = im.Bitmap(outputSize,  
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, m);
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    objImage.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    result = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
                }

                return result;
            }
```

In the View:

```
<img src='<%=Url.Action("GenerateImage")%>' alt="" id="dImage"/>
```

Hope this could help someone.